# Typescript Omit<...>: The non-omitted type is assignable to the omitted type. How to set up types so that this does not occur?

Tags: typescript

Typescript has served me well, and it saves JavaScript from being one of the worst programming languages ever written, but it's not without it's on oddly designed quirks and "gotchas".

Question:

- How does one get the `Omit<...>` to behave in a reliable manner that doesn't create the scenario in the code below? In other words, how might one set up their types so that an error is throw in the code below where one would expect?

```
type NonOmittedObj = {
  keepThisProp: string
  omitThisProp: string
}
type OmittedObj = Omit<NonOmittedObj, 'omitThisProp'>

const nonOmittedObj: NonOmittedObj = {
  keepThisProp: 'foo',
  omitThisProp: 'bar',
}
// It is very counterintuitive that this is allowed and does not throw an error
// If it isn't blatantly obvious why this is counterintuitive, the word "omit" is defined as "to leave out or exclude." With that said, the omitted props are being included, not excluded, so the behavior is contradicting the meaning of the word "omit."
const omittedObj: OmittedObj = nonOmittedObj
```

Here is an analogy showing why this behavior is counter-intuitively designed:

Let's say I have a set of cards named "cards that omit the jokers". Then, when I discover that there are jokers in the deck, I get mad and say "why the f*** are there jokers in this deck??" When `nonOmittedObj` is assigned to `omittedObj`, that feels like taking the jokers from another deck and putting them in the deck labeled "this deck cannot contain any jokers." It feels like it should not be allowed.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-prevent-two-types-from-being-structurally-compatible

Comment: The naming is only counterintuitive if you are misunderstanding where things are being omitted from. Instead of "omit the jokers from this deck of cards", it's more like "omit 'contains jokers' from the description of what an acceptable deck of cards is".  A single deck of cards is more like a *value* where as "description of an acceptable deck of cards" is more like a *type*.  If you don't want jokers in your deck, you need to *explicitly prohibit* them, not just omit them from the description.

Comment: @jcalz Something that is designed intuitively can be understood solely from its interface. Sometimes that is not possible, for example the controls in an airplane. However, I believe that this is not one of those exceptions.

Comment: This is something I learned when I studied video game design, and the principle applies to code design. When designing a video game, if the game needs a long, complicated tutorial to learn, that is a red flag that it was badly designed. If the game is designed very well, the game probably doesn't even need a tutorial at all. The user can simply jump in and grok what is going on.

Comment: ‍♂️ I guess we’re not going to see eye-to-eye on this.  I’ll stop trying to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a strict `Omit` you need to define it's removed keys as `never`
https://tsplay.dev/NVY4vw

```
type NonOmittedObj = {
  keepThisProp: string
  omitThisProp: string
}
const nonOmittedObj: NonOmittedObj = {
  keepThisProp: 'foo',
  omitThisProp: 'bar',
}


type SurelyOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? never : T[K]
}
type OmittedObj = Omit<NonOmittedObj, 'omitThisProp'>
//   ^?
// type OmittedObj = { keepThisProp: string; }
type SmittedObj = SurelyOmit<NonOmittedObj, 'omitThisProp'>
//   ^?
// type SmittedObj = { keepThisProp: string; omitThisProp: never; }



const omittedObj: OmittedObj = nonOmittedObj
// ok

const smittedObj: SmittedObj = nonOmittedObj
//    ^!
// Type 'NonOmittedObj' is not assignable to type 'SurelyOmit<NonOmittedObj, "omitThisProp">'.
//   Types of property 'omitThisProp' are incompatible.
//     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

Comment: Works brilliantly. The answer I gave to my own post ended up being flawed (and is now deleted), so I'm very glad you came around to answer this.

Comment: I made the answer long ago, but it got closes for a while, so I waited for a bit

Comment: This also throws an error if we pass in a key to omit in `SurelyOmit` that is not an actual key. `Omit<...>` doesn't even do that. Very impressive

Comment: Whoops, I found an error, but I also fixed it. When I went to use the SmittedObj type, ts was still requiring me to add the "omitThisProp" prop on it.

Comment: I could not edit your answer because the edit queue on SO was too big.

Here is the solution I found:

Comment: ```export type SmiteProp<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<
  {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? never : T[K];
  },
  K
>;```

Comment: All I did was wrap everything around an Omit<...> after the `=`.

Comment: I'm confused about this answer, as it requires `K` to exist as a `never` property, which is essentially impossible. Personally I'd define `type Prohibit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Record<K, never>>`.  (You could constrain `K extends keyof T` if you want instead of `K extends PropertyKey` but I'm not sure that's important.)  This will make sure that there's always `{ omittedProp?: never }` in the result. How should we proceed here? As written this answer is not doing what's asked.  I'd [edit] but I don't want to fundamentally change the answer.